# Intellij: Code highlighted purple in debug mode

Tags: spring-boot, debugging, intellij-idea

[image]

Does anyone know what this purple highlighting means in Intellij debug mode?

Immediately after executing this line in the debugger, the program exits with no error message or error thrown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called "Smart Step Into", and allows you to select the method, that you would like to step into for debugging, if there are multiple method calls in a line (like in your example). To use this feature, you would press `Shift + F7`, and then either click on the method, or use the arrow keys or tab button to choose the method, and then either press `Enter` or `F7` to enter that method.

For reference: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/stepping-through-the-program.html#smart-step-into